# Jetpack Compose with Accompanist Permissions to access local files

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-permissions, runtime-permissions, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I want to use a keystore file that I placed in libs directory.
i added the permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xl`

```kotlin
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.github.dhaval2404.colorpicker,com.datacap.device_connection" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.MANAGE_INPUT_DRIVERS"/>
```

I requested the permission during runtime as well using a `Accompanist Permissions` this way:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun PermissionsRequest(
    permissions: List<String>,
    deniedMessage: String,
    rationaleMessage: String
) {

    val multiplePermissionsState = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(permissions = permissions)
    HandelRequest(
        multiplePermissionsState = multiplePermissionsState,
        deniedContent = { shouldShowRationale ->
            PermissionDeniedContent(
                deniedMessage = deniedMessage,
                rationaleMessage = rationaleMessage,
                shouldShowRationale = shouldShowRationale,
                onRequestPermission = { multiplePermissionsState.launchMultiplePermissionRequest() }
            )
        },
        content = {}
    )
}

@Composable
fun Content(text: String, showButton: Boolean = true, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(50.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Gray),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(text = text, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
        if (showButton) {
            Button(onClick = onClick) {
                Text(text = "Give Permission")
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun HandelRequest(
    multiplePermissionsState: MultiplePermissionsState,
    deniedContent: @Composable (Boolean) -> Unit,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    var shouldShowRationale by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val result = multiplePermissionsState.permissions.all {
        shouldShowRationale = it.status.shouldShowRationale
        it.status == PermissionStatus.Granted
    }
    if (!result) deniedContent(shouldShowRationale)
}

@ExperimentalPermissionsApi
@Composable
fun PermissionDeniedContent(
    deniedMessage: String,
    rationaleMessage: String,
    shouldShowRationale: Boolean,
    onRequestPermission: () -> Unit
) {
    if (shouldShowRationale) {
        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = {},
            title = {
                Text(
                    text = "Permission Request",
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.h6.fontSize,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                    )
                )
            },
            text = {
                Text(rationaleMessage)
            },
            confirmButton = {
                Button(onClick = onRequestPermission) {
                    Text("Give Permission")
                }
            }
        )
    } else {
        Content(text = deniedMessage, onClick = onRequestPermission)
    }
}
```

I asked for these permissions:

```kotlin
val PERMISSIONS_LIST = listOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
```

on the app first run I get the permission request and I give it an access the first one is for using camera and recording videos, the second one for accessing photos and media contents.

but I'm still getting this same error again and again:

> failed with exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: app/libs/keystore/keypos.jks: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

How can fix this issue? I can't use the ssl settings because of this issue.

Comment: Are you trying to access images/video captured by camera or directly trying to access from gallery ?

Comment: The app needs both actually, but also the keystore file in the lib, because it will be used by the ssl protocol by ktor. this --> app/libs/keystore/keypos.jks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that reading a local file from the app package can be done in another way.

I placed the keystore in the `res` directory, in its own directory. and used the context to get it.

```
val file = context?.resources?.openRawResource(R.raw.keypos)
```

This is it.